# How to Insert into table each different value returned from a select query in visual studio

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I got a select query like this:

```
select * from TableA where job="workers"
```

It returns me a couple of row with different idA's.

Then I want to `insert Into Table B`, the same amount of row i got from TableA with each idA's as value.

Like: `Insert into TableB Values(IdB's, Ida's,...)` for as many rows returned from the selected query.

//Edit

I need each numA from TableA where data1=@data1. (i got this from a select query)

@data1 being a parameter I enter.

And for each of theses numA, I want to insert into Table B (numA, @data2)

@Data2 being a parameter i enter.

```
INSERT INTO TableB
                    Select (numCat from TableA)

VALUES        (numcat, @data2);  

WHERE        data2 = @data2
```

How to do this? Thanks

Comment: Are you really using MySQL with visual studio and C#?  It is allowed, but SQL Server is more common.

Comment: They are not the same fields except for the IdA in the table B.
Table B have some fields i have to put values into. (@value).
I get them from somewhere else in my code.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  I thought I understood it, but I don't know if I'm right.

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into TableB (colA, ColB, ColC)
select col1, col2, col3 
from TableA 
where job = 'workers'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into TableB(col1, col2, . . .)
    select a.wcol1, a.wcol2, 'this is a constant', . . .
    from tableA a
    where job = 'workers';
```

EDIT:

I *think* this is the query you want:

```
INSERT INTO TableB
    SELECT a.numCat, @data2
    FROM TableA a
    WHERE a.Data1 = @data1;
```

I don't understand the purpose of your final `where` clause.  That leads me to suspect that you want an `UPDATE`.  The rest of the question, though, suggests and `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

If both tables have the same fields, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO TableB
  (SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE JOB='workers')
```